# React-pdf renderer not working on React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to install react-pdf/renderer on React version 18 using next command

```
npm install @react-pdf/renderer --save
```

but it is not working on version 18.

Do you have any solution?
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: can you paste the error

Comment: Revert back to a version of React that the package recognises as a peer dependency, or submit a GH issue to ask the maintainers to update the package to accept R18.

Comment: Did this ever get fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use react-18-pdf/renderer instead of react-pdf/renderer

```
npm i @react-18-pdf/renderer
```

Comment: This generates a runtime error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-18-pdf/yoga'`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in error, it require react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" as peer dependency. So it will not work with react 18.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your package.json file and it solves the error

```
"overrides": {
  "@react-pdf/renderer": {
    "react": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to install `@react-pdf/renderer` discarding error the [using any of following two methods](https://gist.github.com/gitname/bdc1fb7fe5bd0c22f6656b7905f57cd6)

1.

```
npm install @react-pdf/renderer --legacy-peer-deps
```

2. 

```
"overrides": {
    "@react-pdf/renderer": {
      "react": "^18.0.0"
    }
  },
```

But I would recommend against it since, I was doing the same and faced with error in `next export` due to `@react-pdf/renderer`. Instead I replaced [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) while it is not declarative, it just get the job done for generating PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of @react-pdf/renderer 3.3.8, there is no dependency error anymore.
just install latest version.

```
npm i @react-pdf/renderer@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run it with `--force`, like this:

```
npm i @react-pdf/renderer --force
```

Comment: This will not work. It will crate new errors.